# Am I right to read a nested lua table as argument from C function?

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table

I'm going to implement a function with C language and which will be called by Lua script.

This function should receive a lua table(which even contains an array) as the argument, so I should read the fields in the table.I try to do like below, but my function is crashing when I run it. Can anyone help my find the problem?

```
/*
 function findImage(options)
    imagePath = options.imagePath
    fuzzy = options.fuzzy
    ignoreColors = options.ignoreColor;
    ...
 end

 Call Example:

 findImage {
              imagePath="/var/image.png", 
              fuzzy=0.5,
              ignoreColors={
                             0xffffff, 
                             0x0000ff, 
                             0x2b2b2b
                           }
            }

 */

static int findImgProxy(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_settop(L, 1);
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);

    lua_getfield(L, -1, "imagePath");
    lua_getfield(L, -2, "fuzzy");
    lua_getfield(L, -3, "ignoreColors");

    const char *imagePath = luaL_checkstring(L, -3);
    double fuzzy    = luaL_optint(L, -2, -1);

    int count  = lua_len(L, -1); // how to get the member count of ignoreColor array

    int colors[count];
    for (int i=0; i count; i++) {
        lua_rawgeti(L, 4, i);
        colors[i] = luaL_checkinteger(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_pop(L, 2);

    ...
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`lua_len` doesn't return anything, it only pushes the length on the stack. Use this snippet to get the table length:

```
lua_len(L, -1);
int count = luaL_checkinteger(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Comment: I tried use `int count = lua_rawlen`, which works.Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it works, too. Unlike `lua_rawlen`, `lua_len` *has* to push its result on stack because it may trigger `__len` metamethod, which may return anything from `nil` to `userdata`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count  = lua_len(L, -1); // how to get the member count of ignoreColor array

int colors[count];
for (int i=0; i count; i++)
{
    colors[i] = luaL_checkinteger(L, -1-i);
}
```

The code segment for this looks incorrect (never mind the missing comparision operator in the loop). The correct function for getting the table length is `lua_objlen`. It looks like you're trying to get the numbers out of 'ignoreColor' but you haven't place them on the stack first. As a result `luaL_checkinteger(L, -1-i);` ends up accessing the *wrong indices* on the stack.

You probably want something closer to this for example:

```
int count  = lua_objlen(L, -1);
std::vector<int> colors(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; lua_pop(L, 1))
{
  lua_rawgeti(L, 4, ++i);
  colors.push_back( luaL_checkinteger(L, -1) );
}
```

If you're using Lua 5.2, replace `lua_objlen` with:

```
int count  = lua_rawlen(L, -1);
```

Make sure there's enough space on the stack if you're moving a lot of elements from the table. eg. `lua_checkstack`

Comment: `lua_len` is the correct function for getting the table length in Lua 5.2, though it performs an unnecessary metatable check.

Comment: @peterm arrrg they had to go and change the api up :( so annoying

Comment: @greatwolf, thank you for your help. I've edited my code above, could you have a look?

Comment: @Suge Note that variable length array's is an extension of gcc which is why I'm using `vector` in my example.